# US->foreign currency abstraction for US-based payment gateways

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

In the case of payment gateways, if the gateway is US-based and can only charge in dollars, but can charge foreign debit/credit cards, and you want to act on countries where the currency is *not* USD, and you can't/do not want to apply for a local payment gateway, what could you do, programming-wise?

I was thinking about converting the amount in USD to the the specific currency. Problem is:

- I don't know where to get real-time accurate exchange-rate data
- Not sure if I get the data from somewhere, if the client's card processor will actually charge that exact price

Do you guys know any best-practices for that? I think another way would be to just charge in dollars, and then let the client know that approximate amount in his/her local currency, but again, I'm not sure where to get an updated currency conversion.

Does any of you have gone through a similar scenario?

PS.: Paypal is not an option.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currency conversion takes place by your customer's bank, so there's unfortunately no central market through which you can even make estimates.

There are some APIs that you can use to make an estimate, though it's mostly just a guess. If you use one of these, I would make sure to make it clear to your customers that the price may vary depending on their bank.

Overall, I've found the best practice is just to display your prices in the supported currency (e.g., USD) and mention to your customers that it might vary. As we continue to [expand internationally](https://stripe.com/global), you can take advantage of our local currency offerings to make more exact charges.

Comment: Paypal does it, as well as Clickbank. I wonder how they do it. Anyway, thank your the answer.